# Using AJAX in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, ajax, ajax-toolkit

I want to create a picklist of all objects of my salesforce org. by the help of AJAX, without using apex controller.I want to achive this functionality by VF page only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using the `describeGlobal()` method from the [AJAX toolkit](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_ajax.pdf):

```
<apex:page title="Object List">

    <apex:pageBlock title="Object List">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <label for="object-list">Object List</label>
                <apex:outputPanel>
                    <!-- select list would be generated dynamically -->
                    <div id="selectContainer"></div>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <!-- getting the session -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    </script>

    <!-- script required for making AJAX call -->
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     

        // fetch the container div
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("selectContainer");

        // create and append select list
        var selectList = document.createElement("select");
        selectList.id = "object-select";
        myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

        // make an AJAX call
        var result = sforce.connection.describeGlobal();

        // create and append the options
        var sobjects = result.getArray("sobjects");
        for (var i=0; i<sobjects.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = sobjects[i].name;
            option.text = sobjects[i].label;
            selectList.appendChild(option);
        }

    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Note here, you would need `connection.js` file which is a Standard Salesforce JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apex remoting for that, so you will be calling an apex class from your ajax method, but It's impossible to do that without calling apex, all you need to do is create a class that calls schema.getDescribe to get a map with all the objects in your org, then just send it back to your ajax as a JSON and convert it to a picklist

Comment: Nothing is impossible my friend!

Comment: .Thanks its really appreciating.If I want to fetch all the records, on selection of each object in the Active widget then what should be my approach.

Comment: Well, of course it is if you want to keep the Salesforce MVC pattern. Nice solution by the way!